# Error message from NDSolve using WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am working with the following `NDSolve` expression:

```
sol = 
  NDSolve[{
      (x[r] (0.9628102243099506` + (20 r^3 y''[r])/y[r]))/r^4 == (5 x''[r])/r, 
      1000 (2 (x'[r])^2 + 2 x[r] x''[r]) + 250 (2 (y'[r])^2 + 2 y[r] y''[r]) == 
        -(17.65185212647424`/r), 
      x[1] == 0, y[1] == 0.25435588063893033`, 
      y'[1] == -0.011618552862714042`, x'[1] == 21/128,
      WhenEvent[y[r] == 0, end = r; "StopIntegration"]},
    {x, y}, {r, 1, 2.381047528519592`}]
```

I can plot `x[r]`, `y[r]`, but I get the message:

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>

If I delete the `WhenEvent` expression in the original code, I can numerically solve the equation without any error message.

When I look at the plots with and without the `WhenEvent` expression, the two plots are exactly the same within the region that they share.

Why am I getting the error message? can I ignore it, since the plot looks perfect.

Comment: @Pickett thanks very much. why do not you answer it, so I can choose yours to be the correct one

Comment: ok thanks, I wrote it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
```

It only happens with `WhenEvent`. The requirement of `WhenEvent` is `y[r]==0`. One of the equations in your system has in it

```
(20 r^3 y''[r])/y[r])
```

which is a potential troublemaker because it is 1/0 for `y[r]==0`. If you change the `WhenEvent` condition to anything else such as `y[r] == 10^(-6)` the error message disappears.

The error message appears because when you tell `NDSolve` to find an event at `y[r]==0` it has to figure out exactly when that event is. When it evaluates the original expression for `y[r]==0` that causes the error message.

One infinite expression does not a faulty solution make. This single data point does not affect the overall solution, `NDSolve` can't use it so it will just ignore it. If the error message bothers you you can hide it using `Quiet`.